# Unable to make a desktop like container in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to make a desktop container kind of frame in Python so that from the menu bar I choose the option the window would open in that desktop pane, Like we use to deal with the Professional Applications.

Here is the Snapshot of the GUI. In the Snapshot the above Menu bar has lots of cascaded options as well. As the User choose the cascaded option, a new window should open below the Menu bar (Empty space in snap), and when the other option is chosen the previous frame should also be there and these sub frames should also have close,minimize and maximize button (e.g. Minimize Minimizes to the bottom of the frame space above the status bar

[image: May Application]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create what is commonly referred to as a "Multiple Document Interface", or MDI. This was popular back in the 80's and early 90's, but is now generally considered to provide very poor usability.

Tkinter does not natively support MDI applications. You will have to do all the window management yourself. Generally this means that you'll use a canvas for the containing window, and then embed frames within the canvas to represent your windows. You'll have to draw your own window borders and handle resizing. I've seen it done, but it's usually not worth the effort to implement.

Comment: has it changed, because here https://sodocumentation.net/tkinter I read: Note: It's possible to inherit from just about any tkinter widget, including the root window. Inheriting from tkinter.Frame is at least arguably the most flexible in that it supports multiple document interfaces (MDI), single document interfaces (SDI), single page applications, and multiple-page applications.

Comment: @pippo1980: no, nothing has changed. MDI applications haven't been considered good UI for decades.